# Unable to access Site Navigation page

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation

I am unable to access site navigation page and every time I click on '**Navigation**' under '**Site Settings**' it gives me a error with correlation ID.

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx, Error=Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedListItem' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedPage'.  
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.FetchDynamicItems(PublishingWeb pubWeb, NodeTypes includedTypes, Boolean& websFetched, Boolean& pagesFetched)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildrenInner(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode.GetNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes, NodeTypes includedHiddenTypes, Boolean trimmingEnabled, OrderingMethod ordering, AutomaticSortingMethod method, Boolean ascending, Int32 lcid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaNavigationSettingsPage.AddChildrenToControl(String parentId, PortalSiteMapNode node, Int32 depth, Int32 maxDepth)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaNavigationSettingsPage.InitializeNavigationEditSort()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaNavigationSettingsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Is there any item in one of the list that is causing this problem? Can someone help me understand this error?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is trying to cast CachedListItem to CachedPage when a page is not published. Try to publish the page and then set the navigation.

Or try this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/invalidcastexception-when-opening-root-level-navigation-settings-page).